# Android Application Not Responding java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm having this error when this activity is opening
I do believe is the problem is most on bluetooth connection I really don't know how to understand this error

**Error Log**

```
06-16 19:13:31.385 3970-3970/com.example.jaypeetan.mftis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.jaypeetan.mftis, PID: 3970
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.jaypeetan.mftis/com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu.onResume(main_menu.java:134)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5490)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2945)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my main menu
**main_menu.java**

```
    package es.esy.a4ec.ledonoff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class index extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

    Button btnOn, btnOff;

    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    // SPP UUID service
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    private static String address = "30:14:08:13:14:20";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData("1");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData("0");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            try {
                final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e1.getMessage() + ".");
        }

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        try     {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if(btAdapter==null) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void errorExit(String title, String message){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
            msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

            errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your answer please help me to finish this program thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Get the Adapter in OnCreate  method,before getting the remote device from address.

```
 btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Comment: Process: com.example.jaypeetan.mftis, PID: 3179
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.jaypeetan.mftis/com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: sorry its not allowing me to post long comment